# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, 2^{1/3})$ a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I am wondering about the following question: 
Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, 2^{1/3})$ a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

For a finite extension $E/F$, the statement "$E/F$ is Galois" is equivalent to the statement "$E$ is a splitting field of a separable polynomial with coefficients in $F$".

Per the above statement, I believe that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, 2^{1/3})$ is **not** a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. This is because, it doesn't seem to me that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, 2^{1/3})$ is even a splitting field of *any* polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Am I correct? If so, how can I make that last sentence above more rigorous, and actually show it's not a splitting field of any polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't. The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]2$ is $x^3-2$, which has two complex roots. But, the extension in question is a subfield of $\mathbb R$. Your argument doesn't really say anything but restate the definition so...

Comment: So, it can't be the splitting field of a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, since the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ introduces a cubic root of unity ? Why are we only allowed to consider the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/3}$, though ? Aren't we adjoining both $\sqrt{2}$ and $2^{1/3}$ to our base field?

Comment: The point is, a Galois extension contains all of the roots of the minimal polynomials of everything you adjoin. That's both $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt[3]2$. But, the other root of $x^2-2$ is $-\sqrt2$, which is why I didn't mention it.

Comment: Any polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $2^{1/3}$ as a root must have the minimal polynomial $x^3 - 2$ as a factor, and so will have nonreal roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  It isn't a normal extension, as it doesn't have all the roots of $x^3-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct

Galois means algebraic, normal and separable extension. Equivalent conditions to normality of the algebraic extension $E|F$ are:

$\bullet$ For each homomorphism $\sigma: E \to L$, where $L$ is the algebraic closure of $F$, such that $\sigma \vert_{F} = id_F$, $\sigma(E) = E$;

$\bullet$ $E$ is the splitting field of some collection of polynomials in $F[X]$;

$\bullet$ For each irreducible polynomial  $f \in F[X]$, if $f$ has a root in $E$, then it splits in $E$.

Take $X^3 - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$, which is irreducible. It has one root in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, \sqrt{2})$, but doesn't split in this field. To work in your definition, it might be better if you assume that $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, \sqrt{2})$ is a primitive element, and work from there.